# read parameters from url-string and execute proper function

Tags: javascript

I create some kind of "routing system" for RestfulAPI  in function `runUrl` - on input I put url which contains some parameters (ID values) and I want to find this url in `routes` array, execute function given for that route with this parameters, and return that result as `runUrl` result.

```js
function runUrl(url) {
  return projects('f505ecfb74','5e735f505c'); // hardcoded mockup
  // Question: how this function should look like ?
}


let routes = [
  ['/cars', cars ],
  ['/companies/:companyId/cars/:carId/projects', projects ],
  ['/companies/:companyId/room/:roomId', rooms ],
  //... 
];

// list of funtions to execute for given url

function cars() { return ["car1","car2"]; }

function projects(companyId,carId) { return [`proj-${companyId}`,`proj-${carId}`]; }

function rooms(companyId,roomId) { return `room-${companyId}-room-${roomId}` }

// ... (more functions)


// TEST
console.log(runUrl('/companies/f505ecfb74/cars/5e735f505c/projects'));
```

So far I write below function - but I have headache and it doesn't work

```js
function runUrl(url) {
  let route = routes.find( r=> url.match(r[0]) );
  if(route) {
    return route[1](url.match(route[0]));
  }
  return null;
}
```

The parameters values are alpha-numeric strings, parameters names in `routes` array start with `:` and then are alpha-numeric strings too. The number of parameters is arbitrary.

How function `runUrl` should look like?

Comment: Is the `routes` array unchangeable, or can you modify it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match expectes the argument given to it to be a regular expression.  None of your r[0] values are regular expressions

Comment: @CertainPerformance rather unchangeable - but If you have some proposition to change it - fill free to show it

Comment: I'd put regular expressions in there instead, and for the first one that passes, call the appropriate function the matching parameters

Comment: @CertainPerformance - sorry, `routes` should be as simple as possible so putting regexp there are not allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with the match method because it's not meant to be equal between two strings, but I think I found an elegant solution to your problem, maybe it will help you :

```js
let routes = [
  ['/cars', cars ],
  ['/companies/:companyId/cars/:carId/projects', projects ],
  ['/companies/:companyId/room/:roomId', rooms ],
];

function runUrl(url) {
  let arrUrl = url.split('/') // it will make an array with any value after /
  let route = routes.find( r=> arrUrl.length === r[0].split('/').length ); // it supposed to be equal by length
  if(route) {
    let params = arrUrl.filter(p => p && p.match(/\d+/)) // it will cut only the ids (string with number)
    return route[1](params);
  }
  return null;
}


// list of funtions to execute for given url

function cars() { 
  return ["car1","car2"];
}

function projects(array) { 
  return [`proj-${array[0]}`,`proj-${array[1]}`];
}

function rooms(array) {
  return `company-${array[0]}-room-${array[1]}`;
}

// ... (more functions)
  

// TEST
console.log(runUrl('/cars'))
console.log(runUrl('/companies/f505ecfb74/cars/5e735f505c/projects'))
console.log(runUrl('/companies/f505ecfb74/room/5e735f505c'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my proposition, similar to [tomer raitz idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61806412/860099) but use regexp to detect parameters

```js
function runUrl(url) {
    let result = undefined;
    let u = url.split("/");
    
    routes.find( ([route,func]) => {
        let r = route.split("/");
        if(r.length==u.length && r.every( (el,i) => /^:/.test(el) || el===u[i] ) ){
            let params = u.filter((el,i)=> /^:/.test(r[i]));
            result = func.call(this,...params);
            return true;
        }            
        return false;
    })  
    return result;      
}



// -----------
// TEST
// -----------

let routes = [
  ['/cars', cars ],
  ['/companies/:companyId/cars/:carId/projects', projects ],
  ['/companies/:companyId/room/:roomId', rooms ],
  //... 
];
function cars() { return ["car1","car2"]; }
function projects(companyId,carId) { return [`proj-${companyId}`,`proj-${carId}`]; }
function rooms(companyId,roomId) { return `room-${companyId}-room-${roomId}`; }


// TEST
console.log(runUrl('/companies/f505ecfb74/cars/5e735f505c/projects'));
console.log(runUrl('/cars'))
console.log(runUrl('/companies/ABC123/room/DEF5678'))
```

Comment: Thank for this post, actually, I succeeded add "API" style in a WebSocket connection request based on your idea.